# Flutter: InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic> in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get some data from an api but it keeps giving me this error. the same error occured for other data models but it worked on itslef but this time it isn't.

My data model :

```
class StoresModel {
final id;
final url;
final List<StoreModel> store;

StoresModel(this.id,this.url,this.store);

StoresModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : id=json["id"]??"",
    url=json["url"]??"",
    store=(json["store"]as 
  List)?.map((i)=>StoreModel.fromJson(i))?.toList() 
 ?? []; // Here's the error !!

} 
 class StoreModel {
 final id;
 final name;

StoreModel(this.id,this.name);

StoreModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : id=json["id"]??"",
    name=json["name"]??"";
}
```

The API :

```
"stores": [
{

"id": 290375,
"url": "https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP1004-CUSA00419_00-GTAVDIGITALDOWNL",
"store": {
"id": 3,
"name": "PlayStation Store",
"slug": "playstation-store",
"domain": "store.playstation.com",
"games_count": 7377,
"image_background": 
"https://media.rawg.io/media/games/328/3283617cb7d75d67257fc58339188742.jpg"
 }
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output API, store is an `Object`, not `List`.
So it should be

```
final StoreModel store;
```

You have to change fromJson method for store

```
store = json['store'] == null
        ? null
        : StoreModel.fromJson(json['store'] as Map<String, dynamic>)
```

Comment: it shows me this error :Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => StoreModel' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'